# AngularJS: CSS classes, ng-repeat, search box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In AngularJS, I have an ng-repeat element and a search box.

I can use a filter on the ng-repeat to show/hide elements based on a search criteria.

How can I apply a CSS class to elements based on a search criteria?
- i.e. make all elements that match the search criteria blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `ng-class` to conditionally apply the class?

```
<input ng-model="search" type="text" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'found': find(item.text, search)}">{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

Then in your controller, something like this:

```
$scope.find = function(text, search) {
    if(!text || !search) return false;
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Here is a [working CodePen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/Iakvj).

If you prefer to use the existing `filter` implementation, you can pull it out and use it:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    var filterFilter = $filter('filter');

    $scope.findViaFilter = function(text, search) {
        if(!text || !search) return false;
        return filterFilter([text], search).length > 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! did not know you could use filterFilter directly.

Answer (score 0):

heres a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zA7QN/52/

```
<div ng-controller="BabeController">
    <input ng-model="filter" />
<ul  >
    <li ng-repeat="babe in babeList">
            <span ng-class="{true: 'babe-hot', false:'babe-name'}[(filter == babe)]">{{babe}}</span>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>


.babe-name { color: blue;}
.babe-hot { color:red }


function BabeController($scope) {
    $scope.filter = '';
    $scope.babeList = [ 'angelina','scarlett','mila','megan'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to use the same functionality as the built in filter filter (the worst name ever) but instead of removing items that do not pass the filter, you just want to highlight the ones that do pass the filter.

The actual value checking function is not exposed, but it's easy to extract from the source; it's the `filterFilter` implementation.  You would use this to create a single valued filter that wraps the `predicate.check` function.  This part is fairly easy and now you can run the default filter function on a single value.

```
app.filter('singleValueFilter', [function() {
  return function(valueToCheck, expression, comperator) {
    var predicates = [];
    predicates.check = function(value) {
      for (var j = 0; j < predicates.length; j++) {
        if(!predicates[j](value)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return predicates.length > 0;
    };
    switch(typeof comperator) {
      case "function":
        break;
      case "boolean":
        if(comperator == true) {
          comperator = function(obj, text) {
            return angular.equals(obj, text);
          };
          break;
        }
      default:
        comperator = function(obj, text) {
          text = (''+text).toLowerCase();
          return (''+obj).toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
        };
    }
    var search = function(obj, text){
      if (typeof text == 'string' && text.charAt(0) === '!') {
        return !search(obj, text.substr(1));
      }
      switch (typeof obj) {
        case "boolean":
        case "number":
        case "string":
          return comperator(obj, text);
        case "object":
          switch (typeof text) {
            case "object":
              return comperator(obj, text);
            default:
              for ( var objKey in obj) {
                if (objKey.charAt(0) !== '$' && search(obj[objKey], text)) {
                  return true;
                }
              }
              break;
          }
          return false;
        case "array":
          for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (search(obj[i], text)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    };
    switch (typeof expression) {
      case "boolean":
      case "number":
      case "string":
        expression = {$:expression};
      case "object":
        for (var key in expression) {
          if (key == '$') {
            (function() {
              if (!expression[key]) return;
              var path = key;
              predicates.push(function(value) {
                return search(value, expression[path]);
              });
            })();
          } else {
            (function() {
              if (!expression[key]) return;
              var path = key;
              predicates.push(function(value) {
                return search(getter(value,path), expression[path]);
              });
            })();
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'function':
        predicates.push(expression);
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }
    return predicates.check(valueToCheck);
  };
}]);
```

[note: you might have to include the `getter` function if you are minimizing this]

Now the hard part.  You want to highlight a list item based on whether it matches this or not.  Setting a class on the element is the best way to go about this, as the other answers point out, however it's more complicated than they make it seem.

In order to dynamically update the selected property, `ng-class` has to reference a property of the scope and not just attempt to use a compiled value.  i.e. something like:

```
<span ng-class="{ 'selected': {{ listItem | singleValueFilter:filterTerm }} }">{{ listItem.name }}</span>
```

wont work because it will actually render a template that doesn't reference the scope once it's compiled:

```
<span ng-class="{ 'selected': false }">{{ listItem.name }}</span>
```

You can actually verify this by looking at the dom in the developer tools.  Even if the result of the filter changes it will change the dom to show selected as true, but since it doesn't reference the scope, the apply step will not trigger an update.

At this point you need to point the listItem class selector at a property of the scope and the next problem you need to solve is how to set a property of the scope to the result of a filter specified in the view.  I'm sorry I don't have the answer to that, but hopefully this will give you enough information to narrow down the scope of the problem.

Comment: Wow!  This is really complicated.  Why go through all this?  Certainly don't copy the code from the "Filter" filter.  If you want to re-use the filter, please don't copy and paste the code.  You can simply pull it out and re-use it!  `var filterFilter = $filter('filter');` and then use it: `return filterFilter([valueToCheck], expression, comparator).length > 0;`

Comment: @BrianGenisio Good point, my brain was fried at midnight last night.  I'd edit your code pen so that the entire object is passed to the search function in both examples, not just the text property.  That was the my main goal with this answer, I just did a really poor job of it.